# booking form with availability calendar

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I need a booking  system with availability calendar for my website, something simple with some basic forms.
I want to be able to insert for each post a "book now" button with an availability  calendar for each post(apartment, house)

I've found this [plugin](http://www.mathieu-piot.net/mp-booking/)

It's nice and simple but It doesn't have an availability calendar and online payment support.
So, could you recommend me something which can work with my requirements ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Wordpress Booking Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/booking/), it's quite complete!